# Converting Jquery filterable portfolio to option select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am newbie just modifying a filterable portfolio with option list, below is my modified jquery code. from li items to option select.

I am getting Syntax error from firebug. So where i am doing wrong?

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[data-type~=otw-twentyfour otw-columns]
....value:null},fb.error=function(a){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized ex...

```
jQuery('select').on('change', function (e) {

    jQuery(".otw-portfolio-filter option").removeClass("current");


    // Get the class attribute value of the clicked link

    var $filterClass = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class");


    if ( $filterClass == "all" ) {

        var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("option");

    } else {

        var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("option[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");

    }

    // Call quicksand

    jQuery("ul.otw-portfolio").quicksand( $filteredPortfolio, {

        duration: 500,

        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'

    });


    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("current");

    // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor

    e.preventDefault();

})
```

The PHP Code

```
<?php $taxo = get_object_taxonomies( 'otw-portfolio' );
                foreach ( $taxo as $tax_name ) {
                    $categories = get_categories('taxonomy='.$tax_name);
                    $i = 0; $len = count( $categories );
                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        if ($i == 0) { ?><select name="select" id="select" class="otw-portfolio-filter"> <option value="#" class="all" style="float:right;"><?php _e( 'All', 'otw_pfl' ); ?></option><?php }
                            echo '<option value="#" class="'.$category->category_nicename.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</option>';
                        if ($i == $len - 1) { echo '</select>'; }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last try ;)

```
var $portfolioClone = jQuery(".otw-portfolio").clone();
jQuery('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var $filterClass = jQuery("option:selected", "select").attr("class");

    if ( $filterClass == "all" ) {

            var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li");

        } else {

            var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");

        }



        // Call quicksand

        jQuery("ul.otw-portfolio").quicksand( $filteredPortfolio, {

            duration: 500,

            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'

        });

    // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: I want to use the option select instead of the <li> sorting as its already working and there. http://tinyurl.com/nj6xzaq in this page you will see the "option select" working but not regain rests items with the easeInOutQuad animation.

Comment: Thanks very quick solution and tricky fix, yes i want to keep them both. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$portfolioClone.find("option[data-type~='" + $filterClass + "']");
```

Added single quotes around $filterClass

Comment: Thanks its working but not expected check this link : http://tinyurl.com/nj6xzaq

Anyway Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Try this: jQuery("option:selected", "select").attr("class"); for your $filterClass

Comment: Could you plz re-check the url i am getting the same result.